# How to get a variable from url to ionic variable?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on an Ionic 3 project with the admob plugin. I create two variables (Mybanner and Myinterstital that) store the admob code and I want to get the content of those variable from an external url like that

```
http://example.com/admob.php
```

and then put it here:

```
id: this.Myabanner,
id: this.Myinterstitial,
```

because I want to change the admob code at any time from the website.

```
import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig, AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig, AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  Myabanner= "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
  Myinterstitial= "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private adMobFree: AdMobFree) {
    this.showInterstitialAd();
    this.ionViewDidLoad();
    this.showVideoRewardsAd()
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      id: this.Myabanner,
      isTesting: false,
      autoShow: true
    };
    this.adMobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
    this.adMobFree.banner.prepare()
      .then(() => {

      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

  }
  async showInterstitialAd() {
    try {
      const interstitialConfig: AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig = {
        id: this.Myinterstitial,
        isTesting: false,
        autoShow: true
      }

      this.adMobFree.interstitial.config(interstitialConfig);

      const result = await this.adMobFree.interstitial.prepare();
      console.log(result);
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
  async showVideoRewardsAd() {
    try {
      const videoRewardsConfig: AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig = {
        //id: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917',
        isTesting: true,
        autoShow: true
      }

      this.adMobFree.rewardVideo.config(videoRewardsConfig);

      const result = await this.adMobFree.rewardVideo.prepare();
      console.log(result);
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your PHP, assign your AdMob code in an array and convert that array to JSON output.

In your Ionic, By using Http Cordova plugin you can get that json value.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

constructor(private http: HTTP) { }

...

this.http.get('http://example.com/admob.php', {}, {})
.then(data => {

  console.log(data.status);
  console.log(data.data); // data received by server
  console.log(data.headers);

})

.catch(error => {

  console.log(error.status);
  console.log(error.error); // error message as string
  console.log(error.headers);

});
```

Comment: yeah this the way thanks but how can i store the it into variable